# Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions. Não existe

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, dotnet-cli

Acabei de instalar o VS2019 na minha maquina nova.
E pra testar criei um projeto simples.
Percebi que não tem mais o .net 3.1 e sim o 5.
Mas meus projetos estão na versão 3 e eu preciso que eles rodem, pois mudar não seria uma boa neste momento.

Segunda questão, fui rodar e de repente:

`Erro  NU1101  Não é possível encontrar o pacote Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions. Não existe nenhum pacote com esta ID nas origens: Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages  Project2  C:\Users\Gladson\source\repos\Project2\Project2.csproj`

Tentei instalar pelo NUGET mas sem sucesso. Apresenta a mesma mensagem.

Comment: ja tentou pesquisar por "download .net core 3.1" na internet? sobre a mensagem no nuget, já olhou se está indo buscar o pacote no nuget.org? pelo jeito está indo só buscar nas pastas locais do seu computador. No VS, se for no "Manage Nuget packages", no lado superior direito tem lá "package source" que é onde está indo buscar

Comment: Então com a versão nova eu preciso instalar o .netCore3 é isso ? Sobre onde buscar, eu não entendi o que vc quis dizer, ou como fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mensagem de erro não tem em nada a ver com versão de .Net ou C#... Como o **RicardoPontual** comentou, seu projeto está buscando apenas pacotes locais/offline do nuget e não estão buscando do nuget.org.

Confira as configurações no seu Visual Studio.

Verifique se opção de fazer o download está habilitada
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim como se você possui o repositório do nuget.org configurado corretamente, além de apenas os pacotes offline da Microsoft
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Perfeito, exatamente isso. Funcionou 100%